# Need multiple -format info:-

Tags: graphicsmagick

I need resize image and clean exif data, but outputs exif data from source image `big.jpg`, and output transformed image sizes for `small.jpg`.

That not outputs exif data:

`gm convert big.jpg -format "%w %h %[exif:DateTime]" -strip -resize "250x250>" -write small.jpg info:-`

That not outputs transformed image sizes (small.jpg):

`gm convert big.jpg -format "%w %h %[exif:DateTime]" -write info:- -strip -resize "250x250>" small.jpg`

How to do it correctly?
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I have two *solutions* for you - one ugly one, and one very ugly one! :-)

The first extracts the EXIF data, writes it to `stderr` so it doesn't get passed through the pipe, then pipes the image (in internal MIFF => *Magick Image File Format*) into a second `convert` that does the resize and prints the resized sizes:

```
gm convert big.jpg -format "%[exif:DateTime]" -write info:/dev/fd/2 miff:- | gm convert miff:- -strip -resize "250x250>" -format "%w %h" -write info:- small.jpg
2017:04:06 09:12:02
250 107
```

The second method is maybe more efficient as it only loads the original image once and stores it in an MPR (*Magick Persistent Register*) between the two processing steps. The two steps are run inside a single GraphicsMagick `batch` process:

```
cat - <<EOF | gm batch -prompt off
convert big.jpg -write mpr:orig -format "%[exif:DateTime]" info:-
convert mpr:orig -strip -resize "250x250>" -format "%w %h" -write small.jpg info:-
EOF
```

Both of these contain *"bashisms"* so you would need to run them under `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know how to do this in two calls :)
I want to be beautiful in one call.

Comment: Technically, the second one is a single call to `gm batch`.

Comment: We use `gm batch` as child worker process, gets results from stdout, I measured the speed differ by 30%, compared to one call and two, now we do it with two calls.

Comment: It is a pity that can not use dynamic variables, then it would be like that

`convert big.jpg -set myVar %[exif:DateTime]  -format "%w %h %[myVar]" -strip -resize "250x250>" -write small.jpg info:-`

Comment: That is exactly how it would work if you had chosen **ImageMagick** rather than **GraphicsMagick** - just replace your `convert` with `magick`

Comment: In `ImageMagick` there is a `batch` interactive mode?